# JTextArea - get rid of extra line

Tags: java, swing

When I use `JTextArea` I always get output:

xxxxxxxxxx
FirstLine
LastLine

xxxxxxxxxx

Where xxxxxx is the border of text area. Instead I would like it to be without extra line at the end. Like this:

xxxxxxxxx
FirstLine
LastLine
xxxxxxxxx

What should I do?

EDIT:I found a problem in my code when I was formatting code to post it here. It was rather unfortunate combination of factors which escaped my eyes. Please remove the question.

Comment: Post the code snippet which is giving you this problem!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you use `println()`, it always adds new line (`\n`) to the end of your string, you need to add these lines manually, e.g. `print(line1 + "\n" + line2)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a trailing `\n` in your document. Remove it to get rid of the empty last line.